# Not loading images when setting bg-url dynamically with next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Running into a weird problem when I'm trying to set the background image dynamically from prop value. Here is my code:

```
<div className={"bg-cover bg-[url('" + props.img_src + "')]"}></div>
```

When I first add a new image (located at img_src="/img.png"), nothing gets rendered. I look at the JS console for network request and nothing was sent. However, when I add in this line:

```
<div className={"bg-cover bg-[url('" + props.img_src + "')]"}></div>
<div className={"bg-cover bg-[url('/img.png')]"}></div>
```

Suddenly, both images get rendered. Now I remove the last line, and my code becomes the exact code as I had before:

```
<div className={"bg-cover bg-[url('" + props.img_src + "')]"}></div>
```

Now it renders properly. What exactly is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of `tree-shaking` property, which means that any `class` that wasn't specified in your **source files** won't be created in the **output file**.

From the [docs:](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth)

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings in your source files.

> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS.

If you want the dynamic classes to work either you need to

1. Use it else where in the project so that it is generated in the output file (Your case)
2. [Safelist](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) all the images before-hand.

   Sample Code:

   ```
   module.exports = {
      content: [
         ...
      ],
      safelist: [
      {
        pattern: /bg-+/,
      },
    ],
    ...
   }
   ```